# is the wife of the brother of my grandmother a mahram?

Tags: mahram

Is the wife of my granduncle(the brother of my mother's mother) a mahram?
This photo doesn't go into detail.

[image]

Comment: why the dislike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure who made the chart and upon what Quranic evidence, but the wife of your granduncle is not a mahram, neither is the wife of your uncle.

Keep in mind, mahram is a term not clearly defined in Islam.  It's more of a cultural influence people came to add onto religion and sometimes it leads to funny things:

Once a woman marries, every man becomes her mahram, since no man can marry a married woman and she is forbidden (moharm) for them. [Arabic poetry]

Comment: it is in wikipedia